# querying Amazon Aurora with Java

Tags: amazon-web-services

I apologize if this is too broad, but I am very new to AWS and I have a specific task I want to do but I can't seem to find any resources to explain how to do it.

I have a Java application that at a high level manages data, and I want that application to be able to store and retrieve information from Amazon Aurora. The simplest task I want to achieve is to be able to run the query "SELECT * FROM Table1" (where Table1 is some example table name in Aurora) from Java. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about how AWS works, because I've thus far been drowning in a sea of links to AWS SDKs, none of which seem to be relevant to this task.

If anyone could provide some concrete information toward how I could achieve this task, what I'm missing about AWS, etc, I would really appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the AWS SDK to query an RDS database. The API/SDK is for managing the servers themselves, not for accessing the RDBMS software running on the servers. You would connect to AWS Aurora via Java just like you would connect to any other MySQL database (or PostgreSQL if you are using that version of Aurora), via [the JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). There's nothing AWS specific about that, other than making sure your code is running from a location that has access to the RDS instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had never interfaced with a MySQL server outside of a CLI before, so I was having a lot of trouble figuring this stuff out, but reading through the documentation for connector/j and I feel much more cleared up now :)

Comment: There are also frameworks/tools such as Spring that make it a lot easier to work with than using the raw JDBC driver directly. And you will probably want to look into JDBC connection pooling before deploying your application to production.